# Ubuntu startup login not coming, shows black screen with GNU GRUB prompt instead

Tags: 12.04, grub2, wubi, gnu

I used the `System Restore` in my Windows to fix a certain problem and thereafter recognized that my dual-booting machine's OS Ubuntu 12.04 LTE is not working!

Ubuntu was installed in my machine using `wubi.exe` and unfortunately it resides in the same hard disk partition of Windows 7.

I was surprised to see that the folders `unp305710732022077260.mdmp` under the installation directory of Ubuntu shows 'Crash Dump file'!.

I think that's why Ubuntu normal start-up screen is not working, GNU Grub appears.

I tried a number of things:

I restarted the machine several times
I inserted the contents of hidden folder `found0000` under Ubuntu installation directory and placed them under /disk folder of Ubuntu renaming them as `root.disk`.

Once again I was taken aback when i saw that the previous `root.disk` named file showed size 0 B!
I typed a number of things on the Ubuntu GNU Grub screen but all in vain as was never able to at least come out of that `grub>` command of black screen and go somewhere else.

Nothing worked for me. It's still the same. I cannot even uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall as my Ubuntu OS has `Hadoop`, `Hive` installed in it.

Uninstalling will totally remove all such installations and redoing all of them would just be a nightmare! Is there any way-out ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your lost of data.

**There are a few problems here.**

- The first problem is that the 12.04 LTE is unsorted as it has reached it 5 year end of life cycle.
- The wubi  installation is contained in the root.disk file.  The unavailability of that file makes the running of the wubi installation (which is a program running under Windows) impossible.
- Recovering Windows data file under Windows is off topic on this forum.  If there is a chance to recover the data file, you would have to use a Windows support forum for their provided tools and procedures.

**Resolve**

Outside of the lost OS your recourse is installing Ubuntu on it's own partition where it won't be dependent on Windows and you'll have the normal Linux and Ubuntu tools for recovering from failed startups and recovering data from those installations.

Comment: But in that case, if I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu on a separate hard disk partition using wubi.exe, I would lose all files and folders and programs installed under Ubuntu. How to restore these installations? Isn't there any way to revive other than uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not suggesting an Uninstall.  From the description of your question, your previous **wubi.exe** install is lost.  The installation is a file that you had described as lost.  It's a file that resides in Windows.  Recovering Windows files is a Windows problem of which you might get a different conclusion for a Windows support channel such as http://superuser.com (asking how to recover a file with zero bytes).  My resolution for you for running Ubuntu is to install **Ubuntu**, not **wubi.exe**.  Reinstalling **wubi.exe** exposes you to the same risk (of losing the data file under Windows).

Comment: If I want to install Ubuntu without wubi.exe, how will I be able to retrieve my files from Ubuntu installed previously using wubi.exe as on selecting it from Bootstrap Loader, it only moves to GNU Grub screen! No chance to reach Ubuntu login screen. Installing Ubuntu once again won;t fix this files recovery problem, right?

Comment: You are seeing the grub menu.  The grub menu is coming from Windows.  The grub menu is looking for the Grub file where **all your Ubuntu files are**.  You will have to ask in a Windows support forum how to recover files that Windows has somehow lost.  There is a chance that someone supporting Windows may know of a way.  If you lost a file that was under Ubuntu (not Windows) I would suggest running [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download), of which I could support.  A windows support resource may be able to help you to recover your **lost data file**.

Comment: ... by the way, If you loose a file, the more you use the computer/partition that has the file becomes the less likely of recovering the file.

Comment: I have downloaded the ISO file(.iso file) of Ubuntu 16 but could not use the option 'burn disk image' as it shows message 'The selected disk image file isn't valid'. How to install Ubuntu now using the ISO file? Installing through wubi.exe could be easier but as you said, one should refrain from it to avoid risks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53637/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-queen).

Comment: I have replied via chat. Please check and answer..