# Dual-booted Ubuntu dark grub screen appears, previous OS not loaded even!

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-one, grubrescue

My PC already had a Ubuntu server installed on it and unfortunately the DVD containing Ubuntu desktop server had been inserted into it. I unselected the option of keeping OS Ubuntu alone and then manually defined certain partitions for installing Ubuntu. These partitions had to be formatted for Ubuntu. All of a sudden the installer crashed and things came to an end! On restarting the machine, I was surprised to find that no option of choosing OS was coming instead a dark screen containing 'grub>wrong file system's appeared on screen.

My question is:
Are the rest OS gone permanently? But I didn't select that option while installing Ubuntu!

2. Please suggest a proper way to retrieve at least the previous Windows 7 OS installed in my machine.

The PC is absolutely useless. Nothing appears just that cursed dark screen.

Should I load BIOS defaults to fix problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu startup login not coming, shows black screen with GNU GRUB prompt instead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/883249/ubuntu-startup-login-not-coming-shows-black-screen-with-gnu-grub-prompt-instead)

Comment: This comment already explained it all: http://askubuntu.com/questions/883249/ubuntu-startup-login-not-coming-shows-black-screen-with-gnu-grub-prompt-instead#comment1377710_883292